# Create a file in every folder in a directory

Tags: python, for-loop, mkdir

I have a directory with hundreds of folders and subfolders and subfolders within subfolders (in windows).

I'm just trying to create a small txt file with the word "test" in all of these folders.

I've tried something like this but can't get it to work properly:

```
for i in root_dir:
    filename = "test.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("Test")
```

attempt2

```
#only makes one file in the root directory - no sub directories though
import os

root_path8 = r'C:\Users\max\Downloads\users_visual\mgr8\mgr7\mgr6'

for i in next(os.walk(root_path8))[1]:
#         print(j)
    print(i)
    root_dir = root_path8
    filename = "test.txt"
    filepath = os.path.join(root_dir, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(root_dir):
        os.makedirs(root_dir)
    f = open(filepath, "a")
    f.write("Test")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `walk` to get all subfolders and sub-subfolders etc. within your directory. This iteration returns 3 values (current folder, subfolders, files); pass the first value to `open`, using `os.path.join` to concatenate the folder name and the file name. E.g.

```
import os
folder_iter = os.walk(root_dir)
for current_folder, _, _ in folder_iter:
    filename = "test.txt"
    with open(os.path.join(current_folder, filename), "w") as f:
        f.write("Test")
```

BTW if it's the same file in every case, i.e. you don't need to CREATE each file separately, probably a more efficient way would be to create one file to begin with and then copy it to each folder in the iteration.